# Alamofire NSURLRequest via POST method doesn't work

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, nsurlrequest

I'm new to swift and iOS and trying to use Alamofire and router for them, which returns NSMutableURLRequest, but my code didn't work. 
 So I just made one NSURLRequest for test, and requested it but results was same.
Here is my code. I'm currently using Alamofire and SwiftyJSON.

```
let params = ["Id": "1234567", "Token": "something"]
    let url = NSURL(string: "myurl")
    var request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url!)
    request.HTTPMethod = Alamofire.Method.POST.rawValue
    let encoding = Alamofire.ParameterEncoding.JSON
    (request, _) = encoding.encode(request, parameters: params)

Alamofire.request(request)
        .validate()
        .responseJSON { response in
            switch response.result {
            case .Success:
                if let value = response.result.value {
                    let json = JSON(value)
                    let token = json["token"].stringValue
                    let error = json["error"].stringValue
                    print("token : \(token), error : \(error)")
                }
            case .Failure(let error):
                // TODO:
                print(error)
            }
    }
```

Above code sends request *without parameters*. Are there any errors on my code?

Comment: Did you try sample on Alamofire example with title post request with json encoded parameters

Comment: Yes, it worked correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've checked your code and before executing encode function your request.HTTPBody is empty, but after it has some data like

`Optional<NSData>
- Some:<7b22546f 6b656e22 3a22736f 6d657468 696e6722 2c224964 223a2231 32333435 3637227d>`

When I call `print(response.request?.HTTPBody)` in `Alamofire response` block, I get the parameters as NSData and the HTTPBody includes the same data as before sending the request so it works.

Try also change the response from **responseJSON** to **responseString**, because if your response can't be parsed to JSON you get Failure.

I think you should check on your URL site if you get correct data.

Instead of your solution I use

`Alamofire.request(method, url, parameters: parameters, encoding: .JSON) .responseString{ response in}`

is the same but shorter and everything is as parameters.